# Can't install drupal through docker-composer

Tags: docker, drupal

Can't install drupal through docker-composer. I installed docker. Downloading packages from github. Then I enter the command "docker-compose up -d @and everything is fine. But when I want to run the next command, "composer create-project drupal/recommended-project" the following problems appear:
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

Problem 1
- drupal/core is locked to version 9.4.8 and an update of this package was not requested.
- drupal/core 9.4.8 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
Problem 2
- drupal/core 9.4.8 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
- drupal/core-recommended 9.4.8 requires drupal/core 9.4.8 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[9.4.8].
- drupal/core-recommended is locked to version 9.4.8 and an update of this package was not requested.

But I can't ignore and run further.
[image]

Comment: you have to run the composer create-project within your container

Comment: It's also not clear what you did as far as "Downloading packages from github". looking at the img of you command line it looks like you might be talking about https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal